# Word for a poem in which lines begin with letters of a previous word

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I was wondering if someone knew the word that describes a poem where each word begins with the letters of a previous word, of if such a word even exists.

An example of such a poem is this: http://crosswords.net23.net/poems/Joshua.html
(I wrote it)

Someone told me there was a word for this kind of thing, but he couldn't remember it, either.

Comment: Here's a neat way to find out things like this yourself: [OneLook.com on the title of this question](http://www.onelook.com/?w=*&loc=revfp2&clue=Word+for+a+poem+in+which+lines+begin+with+letters+of+a+previous+word)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You started with an *[acrostic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acrostic)* of 'JOSHUA':

> An acrostic is a poem or other form of writing in
>   which the first letter, syllable or word of each line, paragraph or
>   other recurring feature in the text spells out a word or a message.

Each instance after that is new acrostic of the word made from each letter in the original.

Comment: Maybe you could call that _recursively acrostic_?

Comment: I considered it.  :)

Comment: As a programmer, I like this description.

Answer (score 5):

The scholarly term *technopaegnia* encompasses all kinds of interplay between the words of a poem and its structure, including (but not limited to) picture poems, acrostics, and other such puzzles. For facts about the term and links to many interesting examples of such poetry – ancient and modern – see [my answer to another question](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/55740/14073).

Comment: +1, Would it be pronounced with a hard 'g' as in "go" or the soft 'g' in "bridge"?

Comment: The usual rule for borrowed Greek is not to pronounce the "g" at all, so "tech-no-PAIN-yah", IPA:/ˌtɛk noʊ ˈpeɪn jə/, US:/ˌtĕk nō ˈpān yə/. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traditional_English_pronunciation_of_Latin#Greek_consonant_clusters